# Is it possible to do a full join in dplyr and keep all the columns used in the join?

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr

I have two tables that I want to do a full join using dplyr, but I don't want it to drop any of the columns. Per the documentation and my own experience it is only keeping the join column for the left hand side. This is a problem when you have a row with a record for the right hand side since the join value is gone.

For example, suppose I have the two tables a and b,

```
customerId | revenue               customerId | state
-----------|---------              -----------|-------
    1      | 2000                       1     |  CA
    2      | 3000                       3     |  GA
    4      | 4000                       4     |  NY
```

doing something like `full_join(a, b, by="customerId")` will produce

```
customerId | revenue | state
-----------|---------|-------
    1      |   2000  |  CA
    2      |   3000  | <NA>
   <NA>    |   <NA>  |  GA
    4      |   4000  |  NY
```

so there is no way to tell which customer that third row is from. The ideal output would be

```
customerId.a | customerId.b | revenue | state
-------------|--------------|---------|-------
      1      |      1       |   2000  |  CA
      2      |     <NA>     |   3000  | <NA>
    <NA>     |      3       |   <NA>  |  GA
      4      |      4       |   4000  |  NY
```

note that this is just a toy example. I'm actually using sparklyr so this is all being run in Spark. Thus, merge won't work here for me. Is there a way to do what I'm looking for in dplyr?

EDIT:
As someone pointed out this actually is working as desired in dplyr itself locally. However, I do see this problem using sparklyr (which uses dplyr). Here is the code to see that:

```
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect("local[4]")
d1 <- data_frame(customerId = c("1","2","4"), revenue=c(2000,3000,4000))
d2 <- data_frame(customerId = c("1","3","4"), state=c("CA", "GA", "NY"))
d1_tbl <- copy_to(sc, d1)
d2_tbl <- copy_to(sc, d2)
full_join(d1_tbl, d2_tbl, by=c("customerId"))
```

Comment: Filed an issue here: https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/663. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem.  All the IDs should be (and are) included in the full join.

```
library(data_frame)
d1 <- data_frame(
  customerId = c(1, 2, 4),
  revenue = c(2000, 3000, 4000)
)
d2 <- data_frame(
  customerId = c(1, 3, 4),
  state = c("CA", "GA", "NY")
)

full_join(d1, d2, by = "customerId")
## # A tibble: 4 × 3
##   customerId revenue state
##        <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>
## 1          1    2000    CA
## 2          2    3000  <NA>
## 3          4    4000    NY
## 4          3      NA    GA
```

---

Update: I can reproduce the problem using `sparklyr`. It's weird behavior, so you might want to file an issue. (Unclear whether the problem is with `sparklyr` or `dplyr` or `DBI` or Spark SQL though.)

Using `explain()`, you can see the SQL that was generated.

```
full_join(d1_tbl, d2_tbl, by=c("customerId")) %>% explain()
```

You can try running a custom SQL query to get what you want, though it's a little messier.

```
library(DBI)
qry <- "SELECT 
    d1.customerID AS customerID1, 
    d2.customerID AS customerID2, 
    d1.revenue, 
    d2.state 
  FROM d1 
  FULL JOIN d2 
    ON d1.customerId = d2.customerId"
dbGetQuery(sc, qry)  
##   customerID1 customerID2 revenue state
## 1           1           1    2000    CA
## 2           2        <NA>    3000  <NA>
## 3        <NA>           3     NaN    GA
## 4           4           4    4000    NY
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I should have tried it myself first. Very interesting. This is definitely not the behavior I'm seeing using sparklyr. I'll create a code example to demonstrate and update my question.

Answer (score 10):

You can create separate identical `customerId` for both data frames before *join*:

```
full_join(
    mutate(a, customerId.a = customerId), 
    mutate(b, customerId.b = customerId), 
    by="customerId"
) %>% select(-customerId)

#  revenue customerId.a state customerId.b
#1    2000            1    CA            1
#2    3000            2  <NA>           NA
#3    4000            4    NY            4
#4      NA           NA    GA            3
```

Comment: I like this idea and may give it a try as a work around. However as Richie points out this does work inside dplyr itself. The behavior is different though using sparklyr.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - the question asks about keeping all of the _columns_ from both tables, which you would need if you wanted to check which rows didn't join, not just one column that contains all of the values of the join key. This answer is by far the simplest way to get to that.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed

```
> full_join(d1_tbl, d2_tbl, by="customerId")
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 3]
# Database: spark_connection
  customerId revenue state
       <chr>   <dbl> <chr>
1          1    2000    CA
2          3     NaN    GA
3          2    3000  <NA>
4          4    4000    NY
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the parameter `keep` in `dplyr::full_join()`.

```
full_join(a, b, by="customerId",keep = TRUE)
```